# setting qml property from Python?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside

I'm trying to use Python, PySide and a sample QML file to make a simple ui.
How can I set the "value" property available in the QML control from my Python app? As of now, the "SpeedDial" show up, but can't figure out how to change it's value.

**Python file:**

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView

# Create Qt application and the QDeclarative view
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QDeclarativeView()
# Create an URL to the QML file
url = QUrl('SpeedDial.qml')

# Set the QML file and show
view.setSource(url)
view.show()
# Enter Qt main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**The qml file:**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item  {
id: root1
property real value : 0

width: 300; height: 300

Image  { id: speed_inactive; x: -9; y: 8; opacity: 0.8; z: 3; source: "pics/speed_inactive.png"

}
Image  {
    id: needle
    x: 136; y: 86
    clip: true
    opacity: root1.opacity
    z: 3
    smooth: true
    source: "pics/needle.png"
    transform: Rotation  {
        id: needleRotation
        origin.x: 5; origin.y: 65
        angle: Math.min(Math.max(-130, root1.value*2.6 - 130), 133)

        Behavior on angle  {
            SpringAnimation  {
                spring: 1.4
                damping: .15
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to control QML properties directly from Python or C++.

Define a Python class that will represent a car with a property `speed`. Instantiate it in QML like that:

```
Car {
    id: car
}
```

and then use its speed:

```
angle: car.speed
```

Comment: Why not? 
Besides, the official docs explains [how to do that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

Comment: @Willy, data can be viewed differently, but by calling QML from C++ it becomes coupuled to one particular representation. There was a video from Qt conference about best QML practices.